# Systemjs builder buildStatic failed with angular 2 rc.1

Tags: angular, systemjs

What is process.js and where is it coming from?

my app consists of

```
System.register(["rxjs/add/operator/map", "rxjs/add/observable/of", "component-1"], function(exports_1) {
    return {
        setters:[
            function (_1) {},
            function (_2) {},
            function (_3) {}
        execute: function() {
        }
    }
});
```

buildStatic gives the following errors...

```
Unhandled rejection Error on fetch for process.js at file:///process.js
        Loading bundle/src/app.js
        Loading component-1
        Loading npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/index
        Loading npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/metadata
        Loading npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1/src/metadata/view
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'process.js'
    at Error (native)
```